# comparisons using merge sort vs selection sort

Tags: java, sorting, merge

I have an array of 10 int, and using selection sort I calculate it takes about 45 comparisons to sort the whole array, but I'm not sure how many it takes to sort using merge sort by my calculation it takes 12 comparisons.... am I right or wrong here?

Thanks in advance

here's the merge method

```
static void merge(int[] first, int[] second, int[] a)
    {
        int iFirst = 0;
        int iSecond = 0;
        int i = 0; 
        //moving the smaller element into a
        while(iFirst < first.length && iSecond < second.length)
        {
            if(first[iFirst] < second[iSecond])
            {
                a[i] = first[iFirst];
                iFirst++;
            }
            else
            {
                a[i] = second[iSecond];
                iSecond++;
            } 
            i++;             
        }
        counter += i;

        //copying the remaning of the first array
        while(iFirst < first.length)
        {
            a[i] = first[iFirst];
            iFirst++; i++;
        }
        //copying the remaining of second array
        while(iSecond < second.length)
        {
            a[i] = second[iSecond];
            iSecond++; i++;
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

To merge an `n`-element array with an `m`-element array, you need `n+m-1` comparisons in the worst case (`min{m,n}` in the best).

So when you split the 10-element array in half, the top-level merge needs up to 9 comparisons. The two 5-element halves need up to 4 comparisons each, makes `9 + 2*4 = 17`. Splitting the 5-element halves in a 2-element and a 3-element part requires up to 1 + 3 comparisons, so the total worst case would be 25 comparisons (9 + 2*4 + 2*3 + 2*1).

```
                10(9)                             9
               /     \
              /       \
             /         \
            /           \
           /             \
          /               \
         /                 \
        5(4)               5(4)                   8
       /   \              /   \
      /     \            /     \
    3(2)     2(1)      3(2)     2(1)              6
   /   \    /   \     /   \    /   \
  2(1)  1  1     1   2(1)  1  1     1             2
 /   \              /   \
1     1            1     1
```

Comment: what do you mean by worst case, at the end you still need to compare all numbers, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you merge `[1,2,3,4,5]` with `[6,7,8,9,10]`, you only need to compare the 6 to the five elements of the first array, after that, no more comparisons are needed. If the largest element of one of the sorted arrays (the shorter) to merge is smaller than the smallest of the other, that's the best case. So the merge needs anything from `min{m,n}` to `m+n-1` comparisons. The tree in my answer gives the worst-case numbers.

Comment: ok here's the thing, I'm trying to count comparisons of a merge sort algorith with this numbers 45 62 98 89 47 59 72 82 45 18, and I'm getting 26 comparisons, as you can see my numbers are all over the place (order wise) they're random number (0-100), as I look at the 10 numbers I think that's the worst case scenario or is it not?

Comment: I put the merge method of the merge sort algorithm on my original post at the top... take a look, and see if my "counter" variable is place in the right place. Thanks

Comment: Yes, `counter` is incremented by the right amount in one of the right places (you could of course increment it by 1 inside the loop). For your example, I get 23 comparisons when splitting in `(n/2,n-n/2)` and 22 when splitting `(n-n/2,n/2)`. That's pretty close to worst-case. How do you get 26?